# Object inside function's parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

In many programming languages, you have function parameters:

```js
function Something(param1, param2, param3) { }
```

However, it seems that function parameters can also appear as the following:

```js
function Something({param1, param2, param3}) { }
```

What is the difference between these two notations in JavaScript?  Which one is better in which circumstances?

Comment: Neither are better, they do different things. The first is three separate parameters, the second only uses one paramter and "destructures" the properties from the expected object.

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter

Comment: To answer your question specifically, it's helpful to pass an options argument when passing them as individual parameters would be unwieldy.